# The HTML5 video tag does not work as expected

Tags: html, html5-video, internet-explorer-11

The HTML5 video tag does not work as expected. When seeking to the last position of the video,   the browser is sometimes crashes(When incorporated in an application, the application is crashe). 
The Issue is occurd in IE11( 11.0.9600.18792IS),Other Browsers (Firefox, Safari, chrome, edge) works as expected.

Is there any workaround?(seeking is must)
Please help me.

■REPRODUCTION PROCEDURE
(0)Open the below attached file in your browser.you can use any video file as sample.mp4

`<video src="sample.mp4" width="640" height="360" poster="sample.jpg" controls preload>
<source src="sample.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>`

(1)Without playing, seeking to the last position of the video.
(2)Seeking to the middle position of the video.
(3)Repeat (1),(2) until (2) is not executed.

■ISSUE
・seeking becomes unusable.
・can not play video.
・sometimes, browser is crashes.

■RELATE
https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/853493/html5-video-tag-error-by-seeking
the the issue is still exists.

Comment: You loaded the `sample.mp4` twice. If you specified `src` in your `<video>` tag, there is no need to use `<source>` tag to specify the video source.

Comment: Please refer to the documentation for proper use: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video